Where to Learn Yekkish Minhagim
I'm a ba'al teshuvah who wants to learn more about yekkish minhagim, as my family comes from Berlin. Are there any good resources (in english would be better but my hebrew isn't too bad)  to learn more?

Worth noting that a lot of resources for yekkish customs that you’ll find floating around are based on western Ashkenazi practice, eg that of Frankfurt. Historically, the practice in Berlin, to the east of the Elbe, had much in common with eastern Ashkenazi practices (so-called minhag Österreich or minhag Polin).

Paging @noachmifrankfurt

Here you'll find a bunch of extremely useful materials: https://moreshesashkenaz.org/en/ I'd also join @JoelK , though the history of the Jews in Berlin mainly starts from the second half of the 17th century, most Jews arriving from other places to the rapidly growing city. So do some thorough family research first.

https://www.hebrewbooks.org/33769
